# FCM use googleapi to add too much topics, then get http return code 429

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, http-error, http-status-code-429

I have 8000 topics to add to firebase, and use `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/xxxx`
post method, after adding 2000 topics, then got the http error 429 (too many requests).

after 24 hours, I still got the error 429, how can I do to resolve it?

And: does anybody know the request limit?

Comment: Why are you adding the topics like that?

Comment: I want to send notifications to different groups in one app

Comment: A topic's behavior is that it gets xreated automatically as soon as a token subscribes to it, and gets removed when there are no longer subscribers. Uou don't have to add them all before you could actually subscribe to them.